# How to apply excerpt inside my XML data on WordPress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I'm pulling out the data from my CRM to my WordPress site using a XML.
It worked actually, but I want to add some functions like read more with the my XML data `{Web_Remarks[1]}` it contains a long description.

Then I tried to add conditions from from my function.php 
like excerpt and edit my descriptions code.

For my functions.php I add

```
<?php
// Customize excerpt for description word count length
function custom_excerpt_length(){
    return 25;
}

add_filter('excerpt_length','custom_excerpt_length');

?>
```

And for my description.php I change my `<?php the_content();?>` to

```
<?php if ($post->post_excerpt) { ?>
        <p>
        <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a href="<?php  the_permalink();?>">Read More&raquo;</a>
        </p>
    <?php }else{
        the_content();
    }
?>
```

I expect the output should be "3Bed room with laundry ro..Read More..."

but what I have now is

"3Bed room with laundry room and sea view with 2 car parkings only for 3.06M!
-Bright
-Spacious
-Sea/Palm view
-Balconies
-Higher floor
-No Construction chance infront
-Prime location
real estate are a Property Investment Firm with an ownership of more than 2500 properties all around the world.These are handpicked exclusive apartments and villas, located within the most prestigious and high-profile developments of Dubai. We do not just believe in customer satisfaction, we aim for customer delight. We understand that our customers define the standard of quality and service and your loyalty must be earned."

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<?php
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if( !empty($excerpt) ) { ?>
   <p>
      <?php echo $excerpt; ?>
      <a href="<?php  the_permalink();?>">Read More&raquo;</a>
   </p>
<?php
} else {
   the_content();
}
```

Or this will be a another method you can use:

```
<?php
// Add this code in functions.php file
function wp_get_custom_excerpt( $limit = '25' ) {
    global $post;

    $content = get_the_excerpt();
    if( empty($content) ) {
        $content = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
    }

    $excerpt = wp_trim_words( $content, $limit, '[...]' );
    return $excerpt;
}

// Remove your excerpt code and just echo function.
echo wp_get_custom_excerpt();
```

Comment: Same nothing happen, It didn't limit my words.

Comment: now the limit is working but when i click read more the whole text description didn't show. I just refresh my page

Comment: You have to use `the_content()` for full content. this function can be used to get the excerpt only.